# Tag <manifest> attribute package has invalid character ' ' Android Manifest

Tags: android, android-manifest

I am getting the error "Tag  attribute package has invalid character ' '." in the Android Manifest, while there is no obviously invalid character. Here is the code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.exampl e.harounsmida.test2"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" >

        <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="15"
            android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

        <application
            android:name="com.example.harounsmida.test2.app.AppController"
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
            <activity
                android:name="com.example.harounsmida.test2.LoginActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:launchMode="singleTop"
                android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <activity
                android:name="com.example.harounsmida.test2.RegisterActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:launchMode="singleTop"
                android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
            <activity
                android:name="com.example.harounsmida.test2.MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:launchMode="singleTop" />
            <activity
                android:name="com.example.harounsmida.test2.UploadToServerActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:launchMode="singleTop" />
        </application>

    </manifest>
```

I don't understand where is the problem, Android Studio says that "File under the build folder are generated and should not be edited." although I didn't edit it.

Comment: Remove space from package name.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Remove space from package name :

```
package="com.exampl e.harounsmida.test2"
```

After removing space :

```
package="com.example.harounsmida.test2"
```

Comment: Oh i didn't see at all, thanks a lot man, it gave me a lot of troubles

Comment: The problem is when I remove the space from the package name and rebuild the project, it come back again with the same error and the space is still there.

Comment: @HarounSMIDA I have the same problem, how did you solve it?

Comment: As you can see, There was a mistake in package name, an extra space

Answer (score 1):

For those who still can't solve this problem :

1 - Close Android Studio. 
2 - Browse to your project directory. 
3 - Rename the project directory name to something else. 
4 - Open Android Studio and open your project (browse to the renamed directory) .
5 - Select Build --> Edit Flavors --> Type something like yourname.myapplication in application id textbox (avoid using non English characters or space)
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5DB3.jpg)

6 - Select Build --> Rebuild Project and you are good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Please consider gradle file and see what you have given as applicationId, any name that you have given in applicationId will be copied from gradle file and pasted to manifest

Also see for space and extra character in package's value

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
package="com.example.harounsmida.test2"
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the space in your package definition because space is not allowed

Answer (score 0):

After throwing the error as mentioned above, Android Studio opens the file "**debug**\AndroidManifest.xml". Note that the Manifest file for the project is "**main**\AndroidManifest.xml". I didn't notice initially and was removing the space from the former file (which Android Studio opens up).

Hope it helps!

Comment: This looks like an answer to me. (It was automatically flagged by the system as potentially low-quality.) But it could be revised to make it more clear.